# Back action button on toolbar of menu item in drawer layout not working

Tags: java, android

I've a drawer layout in my main activity.
On selecting one of its menu item i.e Social (in my case), it jumps to another activity containing fragments tab layout.
The toolbar in my Social activity has a back button <- like this.
I want this to work and return to main content activity but i don't know :

- what to code for this?
- where should i do this?
  Here is the code of Social.Java , where i think needs some change for back button appearing automatically on toolbar but not working.

  ```
  @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_social);


       toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

          getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

          viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
          setupViewPager(viewPager);

          tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
          tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
      }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step:Add this code in onCreat

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Step:2 override onOptionItemSelected

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    ....
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        // do your work
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: but it is appearing itself. How can i set onOptionsitemSelected?

Comment: @Maham your back button on toolbar is option menu. if  you want to perform any action on it you have to override `onOptionsItemSelected` method and you can access that back button with id `android.R.id.home`.